# how to get returned value from common function in firestore cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am bit new to Google Cloud Function for firebase. I am trying to build a common function which can return a JSON object something similar to below. However, looks like the value returned by the function is not a valid object. Can you please help me how to deal with the returning value?

```
exports.dataUpdation = functions.firestore.document('/userReq/{document}').onWrite(async (snap, Context)   => {

var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(snap.after.data()));
var userID = result.userID;

// Want to get returned value from userData (userID,"custProfile")
retunedData = get_userData (userID,collection_name)

console.log("Person's Nickname is " + retunedData.nickName);

});

 function get_userData (userID,collection_name) {

    var userID = doc_userRequirement.userID;

    var queryCustomerProfile = db.collection(collection_name).where("userID", "==", userID);

    queryCustomerProfile.get().then((doc_queryCustomerProfile) => {
      
       
            var CustomerProfile = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc_queryCustomerProfile.docs[0].data()));
            console.log("Nickname printed from get_userData function - "+CustomerProfile.nickName);
            retuningData = { "userId": userID, "nickName" : CustomerProfile.nickName};
            return retuningData;
        

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I observed while testing your code is that the trigger function finishes without waiting for the result of `get_userData()`. This is because of the async nature of your trigger function.

Instead of creating a separate function, I recommend that you design your code like this so you don't encounter async problems:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
  });

const db = admin.firestore();
const userID = 'YOUR_USER_ID';
const collection_name = 'YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME';

exports.dataUpdation = functions.firestore.document('/userReq/{document}').onWrite(async (snap, Context)   => {
    var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(snap.after.data()));

    // Get User Data 
    await db.collection(collection_name).where("userID", "==", userID).get().then((doc_queryCustomerProfile) => {       
      var CustomerProfile = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc_queryCustomerProfile.docs[0].data()));
      console.log("Nickname printed from get_userData function - "+CustomerProfile.nickName);

      var retunedData = { "userId": userID, "nickName" : CustomerProfile.nickName};
      console.log("Person's Nickname is " + retunedData.nickName);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    }); 
});
```

Output:
[image: output]

Comment: What can be an option if I want to make it through a function. I don't mind to keep few async part. Please help.